# flex vs cs3 and swf file size

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm trying to reduce the output size of an SWF file compiled using Flex, and would
also like to know how to remove the gui dependancies.

Using CS3 I can simple create an AS file with the line trace("hello world") compile
it and end up with a swf file which is under 1k and runs instantly.

How can I do this using Flex.. Firstly compiling using mxmlc the swf file is much
larger, and there is always the progress bar when I execute the swf ( I'm assuming it's loading gui control libraries etc ).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As master Yoda would have it: [use Flex framework, or don't use it, there is no strip dependencies.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3hn6fFTxeo)

In other words, if you used almost just any class from `mx.*`, `spark.*` or related package - there's almost no chance you will be able to reduce the size of the SWF below some 500K. You may trick around, as in externalizing some stuff, using RSL to load the framework code separately, but you would only delay the inevitable. The fact is, the framework is but one solid block, which can only be used in its entirety, or none of it.

Comment: Ok say I don't want to use the framework, would I still have access to all the AS3 functions ? i.e trace, attachCamera etc etc.. ?